# VB 2010 Datagrid Display newest in top row

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datagridview

A little background first:
I have a telnet session that is connected to a cluster, it stays connected and receives information periodically. Incoming information is processed and is displayed in a DataGrid. This happens in real time.
Currently the newest information is displayed on the last row (bottom row).
I would like the newest piece of information to be displayed on the top row instead.

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {InfoA, InfoB, InfoC, InfoD, InfoE}) 
DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using DataGridView1.Rows.Add() you can use DataGridView1.Rows.Insert() as this gives you an extra parameter and the ability to add the row at a specific row index, in your case a zero index I think will add the row to the datagrid as the topmost row:

DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, New String() {InfoA, InfoB, InfoC, InfoD, InfoE})

Comment: GeorgeK.......... Thanks for your answer, works perfect. I have searched on and off for the past month for this solution. I hope this helps others as much as it did me.